# What are the screen dimensions of the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, screen

What are the dimensions of the screen on the iPhone 4s and 5s? I mean the length and width of the actual display, in mm or cm. I tried searching for it online but all the sites I looked just provide the resolution and not the actual dimensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be easily calculated with the available information. Since screen dimensions are always specified as the diagonal measurement, the rectangle can be divided into two equal right-angled triangles, with the hypotenuse being the diagonal measurement and the aspect ratio of the display providing inputs for the calculation of the height and width.

**iPhone 4S**

1. Display size (always specified as the diagonal size): [3.5 inches or 89 mm](https://www.apple.com/iphone-4s/specs/)
2. Aspect ratio: [1.5](https://www.apple.com/iphone-4s/specs/) (which is specified as 3:2 and can be calculated from the resolution - 960 x 640 pixels; 960/640 = 1.5)
3. Calculating the height and width when the ratio of the sides and the length of the hypotenuse are known can be done manually or even quicker, by using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).
4. Check this [calculation link for iPhone 4S on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=89+mm+screen+aspect+ratio+1.5). ***The result is 74.05 mm by 49.37 mm.***

**iPhone 5s**

1. Display size (always specified as the diagonal size): [4 inches or 100 mm](https://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/specs/)
2. Aspect ratio: [1.775](https://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/specs/) (which is specified as 16:9 and can be calculated from the resolution - 1136 x 640 pixels; 1136/640 = 1.775)
3. Calculating the height and width when the ratio of the sides and the length of the hypotenuse are known can be done manually or even quicker, by using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).
4. Check this [calculation link for iPhone 5s on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100+mm+screen+aspect+ratio+1.775). ***The result is 87.12 mm by 49.08 mm.***

Comment: Talk about a comprehensive answer! Awesome!

Comment: Great work Michael and M K, this was the exact answer I was looking for. To choose between models, I made two cardboard cutouts of the 6's to see how they felt in my hand since the shop ones are on bulky chain fixings. Thus the screen size was important too, cheers. Not that there is any stock in Australia!!

Comment: Calculation links on Wolfram Alpha return "(not a possible rectangle)"

Answer (score 6):

Wanna add info about iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus:

**iPhone 6**

1. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=119.38+mm+screen+aspect+ratio+1.778
2. 1334 x 750 = 1.778
3. iphone 6 = 104.1 mm x 58.52 mm

**iPhone 6 plus**

1. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=139.7+mm+screen+aspect+ratio+1.778
2. 1920 x 1080 = 1.778
3. iPhone 6 plus = 121.8 mm x 68.48 mm

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No. But for example I was looking for sizes in mm of all iPhones. But here was only sizes for iPhone 4 and 5... So I calculate sizes for new iPhones and post it here for other people who will search for it.

Comment: @Michael A better approach would be to post a question for the new models and answer it yourself.